# Why can I not receive touch events within my custom UIScrollView subclass?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

i have an uiscrollview with a uiimageview inside. I subclass the uiscrollview but i can not get touches to work touchbegin does not called. What should i do to call uitouch event?

what is wrong?

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface myScrollView : UIScrollView {

}

@end
```

.m

```
#import "myScrollView.h"


@implementation myScrollView


- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    if (touch.view.tag > 0) {
        touch.view.center = location;
    }

    NSLog(@"tag=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the 2.0+ compiler, everything works as expected, but now that I have to use a 3.0+ compiler, my UIScrollView no longer receives the touch events.

I found the answer to the problem here:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21374-uiscrollview-subclass-not-detecting-touches.html

basically, apple removed this ability in 3.0

> In 2.2.1 and earlier, it was possible
>   to prevent a UIScrollView from
>   scrolling by implementing the
>   UIResponder touch methods in a
>   subclass and not calling the
>   superclass' implementation. This was
>   never supported, and often resulted in
>   inconsistent state on the
>   UIScrollView, but it worked in certain
>   specific situations

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn on userInteractionEnabled in the UIImageView (it's off by default for those).

Comment: userinteraction is enabled! both on uiscrollview and uiimageview

Comment: are you trying to get touches for the UIImageView or the UIScrollView?  I think you'll get into trouble overriding -touchesXXX: on a UIScrollView. Have you double checked that your view is getting instantiated, and not a stock UIScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on [Event Handling](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/EventHandling/EventHandling.html) and see if you can't figure anything out from that. You also might try `canBecomeFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use these view?
Do you create them from IB or from the code?
Things to check:

- If you use the IB then make sure that you've set the Class Identity (in View Identity tab in Tools > Inspector) to "myScrollView"
- If you use IB then which parameters have you change from default in both views?
- If you create the views in the code then post your initiation code
- Do you get any method called in "myScrollView" (initializer, for example)?